# Value Relation in QGIS keeps defaulting to the first value in the list no matter what pull down value I select

Tags: qgis, valuerelation

Value Relation in QGIS keeps defaulting to the first value in the list no matter what pull down value I select!
I have 3 value tables in PostGres and the relations and filters all work but when I select the third value filtered from the second table it selects fine when the focus comes off the cell it defaults back to the first value in the list[image]

[image]

This is how I had to key the final table for it to work.
Can someone tell me why this works?  For the life of me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally understood it. The thing is that it saves the 'fkey' under the 'activity' column which technically doesn't exist as a value there. That's why it always takes the first item in the list of values.

Comment: Could you provide a solution? Your answer may explain the reason, but I for one can not see how to solve the issue it self.

Comment: i usually make the first value something like '--not set' and then i patch it with custom constraint like "my_field" IS NOT NULL AND  "my_field" != '--not set' so the user is forced to select some value